# Error when starting service on android startup

Tags: android, android-studio, service, boot, receiver

I am trying to launch a service on startup.  It uses a broadcast receiver that calls startservice that shows a notification to keep a foreground service running.

The service is listed in the manifest as well as the receiver.

The application actually works great on a test device running kit kat.  When i tried it on later android versions the service doesnt start on startup.  I am able to open my app and then call startservice in my app so the service is fine.  If i go to the broadcast receiver and start an intent to start main activity and the app runs on device startup.

If i look at the logcat on startup it says "cannot start service app in background".

Can anyone help me understand what is actually happening on startup?

Comment: Scan Logcat for relevant system messages. Note that on Android 8.0+, you need to call `startForegroundService()` to start a service from a `BroadcastReceiver`.

Comment: Spot on.  Adding the version check to the receiver so that it calls startforegroundservice on later versions.  It seems like quite a bit changed with oreo.